# Removing item from RecyclerView Still shows it in background

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I created a `RecyclerView` that displays items.

Every X items, I have a native ad and beneath it a `TextView` with some title..

The user has an option to delete an item and then I use the following to do so:

```
public void removeAt(int position) {
    items.remove( position );
    notifyItemRemoved( position );
    notifyItemRangeChanged( position, items.size() );
}
```

It does the job good and deletes the item and shifts the whole items one line up.

However, when I scroll over the position of the deleted item it still seems like the image of it is stuck and it shows it in the background between the lines of the `RecyclerView` as follows:

[image]

Any way I can make sure that the deleted item won't appear like this?

SOLUTION:

Setting the background of the title to white did the job.

Comment: I think that dealing with it using a white background can visually make it works, but it may still intercept any touch, click ,... listeners on it if you already registered them

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of this is the `RecyclerView` being inside a `Fragment` that's being inserted twice, often due to being unconditionally added in the Activity's onCreate when it's already there.  Setting the background to white will cover up the issue, but not fix it.

Add some logging (logging when you set the adapter is a good place to do it) to check if your `RecyclerView` is actually getting added more times than you think.